# Android INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE with no previous app installed

Tags: android, installation, apk

Context:
Gradle 4.0.0
useNewApkCreator=false

I have downgraded from targeting API 29 to API 28.
I have no other versions of the APK installed on the test device, which is a Pixel 3XL that has just been factory reset.

I have also tested on Android 9, 10 and 11 devices all without the APK installed (confirmed in Settings - App Manager).

I have tried to increase the version of the app (code and name) multiple times.

I cannot install via Terminal ADB (even with -d downgrade flag) or Android Studio. AS tries to uninstall the non-existant APK before installing and always fails.

Has anyone run into this issue, and if so, how did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following to my /app level build.gradle prevents the error:

```
packagingOptions {
    ...
    exclude 'resources.arsc'
    exclude 'AndroidManifest.xml'
}
```

Why Google cannot make the error output be more indicative of the cause is beyond me.

Comment: thanks so much brother you solved another big problem for me that is 
Zip file '/media/hichemkanon/New Volume/android_studio/Android_Studio_Projects/Android_Ide_console_app/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk' already contains entry 'AndroidManifest.xml', cannot overwrite