# After upgraded to androidX Zip file '...' already contains entry 'AndroidManifest.xml', cannot overwrite Error while build

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm new in Android development and I've been recently assigned to an android project, which was not updated for more than a year. I got the below error when I try to build.

This project was made before android X and I have just migrated to the android X with android studio. Gradle version was 3.8 and now it is 7.0. When the migration and upgrade finished, I started to encounter this problem while building

Please guide me on how I should fix it.

***FAILURE**: Build failed with an exception.***

> What went wrong:
> Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$IncrementalSplitterRunnable
> Zip file 'C:\Users...\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk' already contains entry 'AndroidManifest.xml', cannot overwrite

> Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
> Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
> Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
> See https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
> BUILD FAILED in 3s

Here my gradle files:

### build.gradle(Module:MyApp.app)

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp.app"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 108
        versionName "3.7"
        testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJsUnitRunner'
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            google()
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    namespace 'com.myapp.app'
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation('androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0', {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
})
implementation('androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0', {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
})
implementation('androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0', {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
})
implementation('androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3', {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
})
implementation('com.google.android:flexbox:1.0.0', {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
})
implementation('com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0', {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
})
implementation('com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828', {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
})
implementation('com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0', {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
})
implementation('com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0', {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
})
implementation('com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1', {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
})
implementation('com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1', {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
})
implementation('pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.15', {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
})
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.1.0'
implementation('io.card:android-sdk:5.5.1', {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
})
implementation('com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:5.0.0', {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
})
implementation ('androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3',{
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
})
implementation ('androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0',{
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
})

implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.0.3')

implementation ('com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics',{
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
})
implementation ('com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics',{
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
})

implementation ('com.google.firebase:firebase-core',{
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
})
implementation('com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging', {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
})
implementation('androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.1', {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
})


implementation ('com.facebook.android:facebook-login:12.2.0',{
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
})
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'

implementation('androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0', {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
})

implementation ('androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0',{
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
})
/* implementation('com.smartyads:ad-container:0.4.9', {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
    transitive = true
})*/
implementation ('com.inmobi.monetization:inmobi-ads:8.1.3',{
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
})

}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

### build.gradle(Project:MyApp)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4'
        

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.8.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        flatDir {
            dirs '../libs'
        }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/moat-sdk-builds" }
        maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/smartyads/maven/" }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: What would `exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'` be good for? And why would one want to `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` at the bottom of the script again?

Comment: Did you find the solution then please update

Answer (score 14):

Depending on the Android Studio version and Gradle plugin version you are using, the culprit could be the new packaging tool: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#zipflinger

The easiest way to fall back to using the older tool would be to add this line in the `gradle.properties` file:

```
android.useNewApkCreator=false
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me (same error experienced when building the unit tests in a project imported from Eclipse, even though the main app built without this problem).  I still don't understand _why_ the new APK creator causes this issue - this would be good to know as the option to use the old APK creator is being removed in version 8.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.

Answer (score 2):

this is the only working solution for me :
in your build.gradle file add

```
android {
...
    packagingOptions {
    ...
        exclude 'resources.arsc'
        exclude 'AndroidManifest.xml'
       }
    }
```

taken from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62268286/android-install-failed-version-downgrade-with-no-previous-app-installed)

Comment: good, it works for me

Answer (score 0):

Verify that you do not have an extra AndroidManifest.xml in your project that is not part of a source set.  When I fixed this in an old project recently, I found there was another AndroidManifest.xml in the `resources/` directory.