Building Android apk fails after upgrading Android target sdk to 34
building Android apk fails after upgrading Android target sdk to 34
Report the following error:
Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$IncrementalSplitterRunnable
   > Zip file '/Users/xxx/app/build/intermediates/apk/debug/app-debug.apk' already contains entry 'AndroidManifest.xml', cannot overwrite

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'. 
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Zip file '/Users/xxx/app/build/intermediates/apk/debug/app-debug.apk' already contains entry 'AndroidManifest.xml', cannot overwrite
    at com.android.zipflinger.ZipArchive.validateName(ZipArchive.java:345)
    at com.android.zipflinger.ZipArchive.writeSource(ZipArchive.java:302)
    at com.android.zipflinger.ZipArchive.add(ZipArchive.java:163)
    at com.android.signflinger.SignedApk.add(SignedApk.java:179)
    at com.android.zipflinger.SynchronizedArchive.add(SynchronizedArchive.java:40)
    at com.android.builder.internal.packaging.ApkFlinger.writeZip(ApkFlinger.kt:185)

Does anyone know how to fix it?

you can visit this one for migrate
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72003897/25203130 , make sure your manifest "namespace" was removed. even not work you want to share your manifest as well as build.gradle file.
